# WTForms: nested form field, UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

My form model is defined like this:

```
from com.example.cms.forms import FieldList as MyAppFieldList
from flask_wtf                 import Form
from wtforms                   import fields
from wtforms                   import validators

class FacebookPostTranslationForm(Form):
    language    = fields.StringField('Language', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(min=2, max=2)])
    title       = fields.TextAreaField('Title', [validators.InputRequired()])
    description = fields.TextAreaField('Description', [validators.InputRequired()])
    linkUrl     = fields.StringField('Link', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.URL()])
    pictureUrl  = fields.StringField('Picture', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.URL()])

class FacebookPostTemplateForm(Form):
    name         = fields.StringField('Name', [validators.InputRequired()])
    title        = fields.TextAreaField('Title', [validators.InputRequired()])
    description  = fields.TextAreaField('Description', [validators.InputRequired()])
    linkUrl      = fields.StringField('Link', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.URL()])
    pictureUrl   = fields.StringField('Picture', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.URL()])
    translations = MyAppFieldList(fields.FormField(FacebookPostTranslationForm), [validators.Optional()])

class FacebookPostTemplateCreateForm(FacebookPostTemplateForm):
    pass

class FacebookPostTemplateUpdateForm(FacebookPostTemplateForm):
    pass
```

and then inside HTML template I have:

```
<span id="translationFieldsetHolder">
    {% for translation in form.translations.entries %}
        <fieldset class="translationFieldset">
            <legend>{% if translation.language.data %}{{ translation.language.data|upper }}{% else %}Add{% endif %} Translation</legend>
            {{ render_field(translation.language) }}
            {{ render_field(translation.title, rows=5) }}
            {{ render_field(translation.description, rows=5) }}
            {{ render_field(translation.linkUrl) }}
            {{ render_field(translation.pictureUrl) }}
            {{ translation.csrf_token }}            
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
</span>
```

Everything but *translation.description* renders fine. Namely this line causes problems:

```
{{ render_field(translation.description, rows=5) }}
```

If I replace *description* with *title* it works fine (although it renders *title* twice instead of *title* plus *description*).

With *description* I get the following error:

```
{{ field.label(class="control-label") }}
UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'label'
```

in the macro that starts with:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <div class="control-group {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
        {{ field.label(class="control-label") }}
```

I'm quite new to Python or WTForms. Is there anything special with *description* field name that could cause some problems / clashes?

I can see that the data is correctly delivered to the controller via the web service. There is nothing suspicious in the value of this field.

The [sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpkcrtympwotesb/DescriptionTest.zip?dl=0) to be run. It was extracted from the original sources so at some places it is a mess.

If I change the name of the field it works :(
But it implies I would have to either change it on the web service or somewhere in Python code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Field` itself has `description` kwarg

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, filters=tuple(),
                 description='', id=None, default=None, widget=None,
                 _form=None, _name=None, _prefix='', _translations=None):
```

What you are doing is adding into `FormField(Field)` object that also has `description` inside

```
class FacebookPostTranslationForm(Form):
    description = fields.TextAreaField('Description', [validators.InputRequired()])
```

In template when You call `translation.description` WTForms is returning `Field.description` instead of `FacebookPostTranslationForm.description`

Hope that helps :)